# How to convert photos from heic into jpg?

Tags: macos, photos, heic

On ios devices photos are stored in [heic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Efficiency_Image_File_Format). I turned on the option to "send originals", so when I send a photo from my phone to my mac, it is in heic format. The conversion is only necessary once in a while when some website requires jpg-format. For my own purposes I'd like to stick to the more efficient heic-format.

What ways are there to convert photos heic to jpg on macos? Assume the photo is on the mac file system.
For solutions I would be specially grateful if you could take into account the following preferences:

1. Software that is available on macos by default
2. Software available on homebrew
3. Other ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Preview.app

1. Open the HEIC with Preview.app
2. File > Export...
3. Format: JPEG

In batch:

1. Select all the desired HEIC files in Finder at once (using shift + click or dragging)
2. Right-click > Open with > Preview
3. Use shift + click (or dragging) in Preview to select all the files in the sidebar
4. File > Export Selected Images...
5. Click options in the bottom-left of the dialog
6. Set the format to JPEG
7. Navigate to the location you want to save the new JPEGs
8. Click "Choose" in the bottom-right of the dialog

## Command line (ImageMagick)

```
brew install imagemagick
convert IMG_1234.HEIC image.jpg
```

In batch:

```
for file in *.HEIC ; do convert "$file" "${file%.HEIC}.jpg" ; done
```